# Is it possible to create a regex-constrained type hint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a helper function that converts a `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`-formatted string to a `datetime.datetime`:

```
def ymdt_to_datetime(ymdt: str) -> datetime.datetime:
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(ymdt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I can validate the `ymdt` format in the function itself, but it'd be more useful to have a custom object to use as a type hint for the argument, something like

```
from typing import NewType, Pattern

ymdt_pattern = '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
YmdString = NewType('YmdString', Pattern[ymdt_pattern])

def ymdt_to_datetime(ymdt: YmdString)...
```

Am I going down the wrong rabbit hole?  Should this be an issue in `mypy` or someplace?  Or can this be accomplished with the current type hint implementation (3.61)?

Answer (score 9):

There currently is no way for types to statically verify that your string matches a precise format, unfortunately. This is partially because checking at compile time the exact values a given variable can hold is exceedingly difficult to implement (and in fact, is NP-hard in some cases), and partially because the problem becomes impossible in the face of things like user input. As a result, it's unlikely that this feature will be added to either mypy or the Python typing ecosystem in the near future, if at all.

One potential workaround would be to leverage `NewType`, and carefully control when exactly you construct a string of that format. That is, you could do:

```
from typing import NewType
YmdString = NewType('YmdString', str)

def datetime_to_ymd(d: datetime) -> YmdString:
    # Do conversion here
    return YmdStr(s)

def verify_is_ymd(s: str) -> YmdString:
    # Runtime validation checks here
    return YmdString(s)
```

If you use only functions like these to introduce values of type `YmdString` and do testing to confirm that your 'constructor functions' are working perfectly, you can more or less safely distinguish between strings and `YmdString` at compile time. You'd then want to design your program to minimize how frequently you call these functions to avoid incurring unnecessary overhead, but hopefully, that won't be too onerous to do.

Comment: thanks, @Michael.  Did you mean to call `verify_is_ymd` somewhere in `datetime_to_ymd` or am I missing your point?

Comment: @ZevAverbach -- you could, but it wouldn't be necessary. If you careful  test `datetime_to_ymd` to the point where you're highly confident it's correct, you could omit the runtime checks entirely. (That is, instead of gaining confidence in `datetime_to_ymd` through the type system or via runtime checks, you gain confidence via unit tests). Rather, your other code would call one of those two functions (or other 'constructor functions' you write). Of course, if unit tests weren't enough to convince you of correctness, you could call the validation function within `datetime_to_ymd` anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Using type-hints does nothing in Python and acts as an indication of the type in static checkers. It is not meant to perform any actions, merely annotate a type.

You can't do any validation, all you can do, with type-hints and a checker, is make sure the argument passed in is actually of type `str`.

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  I don't want any actions performed, just wondering whether I can make custom type (a `str` in a very specific format) for the checker to check against.

Comment: @ZevAverbach I see. No, you can't check how a string might look, you can only check its type. The checks made are based on the type so no matter what a `str` object looks like, it's still a `str` object.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here we are five years later and the answer is now **yes**, at least if you're willing to take a third-party library on board and decorate the functions you want to be checked at runtime:

`$ pip install beartype`

```py
import re
from typing import Annotated  # python 3.9+

from beartype import beartype
from beartype.vale import Is

YtdString = Annotated[str, Is[lambda string: re.match('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]', string) is not None]]

@beartype
def just_print_it(ytd_string: YtdString) -> None:
    print(ytd_string)

> just_print_it("hey")

BeartypeCallHintParamViolation: @beartyped just_print_it() parameter ytd_string='hey' violates type hint typing.Annotated[str, Is[<lambda>]], as 'hey' violates validator Is[<lambda>]:
    False == Is[<lambda>].

> just_print_it("2022-12-23 09:09:23")
2022-12-23 09:09:23

> just_print_it("2022-12-23 09:09:2")
BeartypeCallHintParamViolation: @beartyped just_print_it() parameter ytd_string='2022-12-23 09:09:2' violates type hint typing.Annotated[str, Is[<lambda>]], as '2022-12-23 09:09:2' violates validator Is[<lambda>]:
    False == Is[<lambda>].
```

Please note that I'm using the very imperfect regex pattern I originally included in the question, not production-ready.

Then, a hopeful note: The maintainer of `beartype` is hard at work on [an automagical import hook](https://github.com/beartype/beartype/issues/43) which will eliminate the need for decorating functions in order to achieve the above.