# Define string format in function declaration

Tags: python, string, function, declaration, type-hinting

This works:

```
def this_is_a_function(string_variable: str):
    print(string_variable)
```

, but is it possible to go a step further and define the format of a string in the function declaration? Something like:

```
def this_is_a_function(string_variable: str: 'string_format_declaration_here'):
    print(string_variable)
```

Comment: Why do you want to have that when you can do inside?

Comment: @Austin Why do it inside if I can do it at the declaration? Wouldn't it be more pythonic to decline a function call instead of writing code to verify the parameter and then decline the call?

Comment: No, you can't do it. Check the answer to this related question: [Is it possible to create a regex-constrained type hint?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44536263/7851470)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh "It means that any way of accomplishing the task is fine". So, using a syntax of '{part_1}@{part_2}.com' would be fine if it could be implemented. So would something that uses RegEx. Those are the two ways that I have thought of on how to do this, but there may be other ways. So I have left the question ambiguous.