# Type annotation for literal values with a regular form in python

Tags: python, types, mypy

Is it possible to set type annotation for strings like below?

```py
ContainsSlashString = ...

contains_slash1: ContainsSlashString = "foo/bar"      # type checks
contains_slash2: ContainsSlashString = "noslashhere"  # mypy doesn't type check
```

Or more complex types like:

```py
NumberOnlyString = ...

number_only1: NumberOnlyString = "1234123"  # type checks
number_only2: NumberOnlyString = "123hihi"  # mypy doesn't type check
```

Comment: @Lars Thanks, but obviously, I WANT to type check with mypy!

Comment: You can type to a specific set of literals with [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal), but you can't type-check for "strings containing slashes" or "strings that look like numbers". See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44530674/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I don't want a constant `Literal`. I am writing a function, which its params need to have a regular form. I want to check the types with mypy (not in runtime).